# Using RedBeanPHP, findOne() does not find anything

Tags: php, orm, redbean

I have the following code:

```
$tuba = R::findOne("tuba", "photoNum = ?", [$_POST["photoNum"]]);
if(empty($tuba)) exit("<h2 class='text-warning'>No entry with photo number ".$_POST["photoNum"]." found.</h2>");
```

When I pass it a value for photoNum that I know exists in the database, it returns NULL. If I use findAll() then the entry I'm looking for is returned along with all the others. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my problem was that RedBean converts camel case to snake case so my property "photoNum" represented the column "photo_num" in the database.